# Symfony2 enable HOST route parameter in production only

Tags: symfony

is it possible to enable the HOST parameter in symfony2 routing for production only? Or possibly have a dynamic value that i can import from parameters.yml?

Cant seen to find documentation on this.

Comment: i suggest you to use the yml routing strategy so you can override prod conf with the related files

Comment: Yeah i am using that strategy, can i reference a previously defined value in the routing file? and i assume the parameters are loaded before the routin

Comment: Have you tried with the regular expression? From sf 2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a specific routing file for each environment, like `routing_dev.yml` and `routing_prod.yml`.

In your config.yml, load the routing corresponding to your env by doing :

```
# app/config/config.yml
#....
framework:
    router:
         resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_%kernel_environment%.yml"
```

Now, add your custom host based routes in the routing_prod.yml. Example :

```
# app/config/routing_prod.yml
acme_home:
    host: "%domain%"
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeAppBundle:Default:home }

 acme_api:
     host: "api.%domain%"
     path: /
     defaults: { _controller: AcmeAppBundle:Default:api }
```

And

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
domain: home.example.com
```

Hope this is what you need.